# Is thrift running on my HBase master? How to connect to it with Happybase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, thrift, happybase

I am running `krejcmat/hadoop-hbase` docker in pseudo distributed mode. That is master and slaves are running in separate containers on the same machine. After starting the Hadoop cluster and HBase, I start the thrift server on the master node with:

```
hbase thrift start -threadpool
```

I also expose node `9090` (the default Thrift port on the start with `--expose=9090`). I want to use the Happybase library to connect from my host machine to the Hbase running in the Hadoop cluster via the Thrift API. This is the command I use:

```
connection = happybase.Connection('hadoop-hbase-master', 9090)
```

But I receive the error:

> `TTransportException(message="Could not connect to ('hadoop-hbase-master', 9090)", type=1)`

Which means the Thrift API is not reachable. Is it because the Thrift server is not running? Or shall I use some sort of a Thrift client on my host machine? Or shall I run the thrift server on one of the slaves instead of the master?

Thanks,
Sepideh

Answer (score 0):

I start thrift through

> hbase thrift start

and then the following codes are OK.

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('localhost')
```

You may try.